# Point to Point Vs Point To Site vs Site To Site Vs Expressroute in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, point-to-point

We have Inhouse SQL database and Application is running in Azure VM. This is an internal application. SLA is not a constraint. Traffic is also nominal. What network is suitable for me to start with, to keep cost low.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case narrows it down to Site-to-Site or Express Route.

Looking at your statement, I would suggest going with a Site-to-Site tunnel to your Azure VPN Gateway. It's the most cost-effective way but while it's cheaper than ExpressRoute, it also comes with lower bandwidth and higher latency. Also d no SLA guarantees as your tunneled traffic travels over your Internet connection and whatever network device (firewall/router) that is on the on-prem side of the connection.